# Static code analysis for SenseTalk

Tags: parsing, nlp, static-analysis, pmd, static-code-analysis

I am looking for a static code analysis tool for [SenseTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SenseTalk) which can be extended to perform my custom rules. I need to identify dead codes and verify the naming conventions of variables and functions(Bonus: identify duplicate codes).I was not able to find a readily available tool to perform SCA on SenseTalk, although there were few tools which can be extended to a new language like [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/new-language.html). I was also thinking if NLP can be incorporated for this scenario, but not sure on this. Any suggestions on how I can perform SCA on SenseTalk would be useful.